# Square digit sum sequences puzzle

Tags: sequences-and-series

An interesting problem from [Cambridge University press](https://www.cambridge.org/ukschools/news/december-computing-competition/). It is supposed to be solved by programming, but I wondered if there was any way to solve it mathematically.
Here is the problem:

A student has a book containing 411 pages.

She read a certain number of pages on the first day and created a rule to work out how many pages she had to read on each succeeding day.

She decided that the number of pages to be read on the next day should be equal to the square of the sum of the digits of the page she ended at.

For example, if she ended on page 36, then she should read 81 pages on the next day as this is the square of 6 + 3.

She found that on the sixth day, the number of pages she had set herself to read took her exactly to the final page of the book.

How many pages did she read each day?

Comment: Well, this is not really a question. The original one was "Write a program that will calculate how many pages she read each day." I suppose you're asking if there's closed formula instead of that?

Comment: @RespawnedFluff Yes, or some way of working it out without brute force.

Comment: I don't see why you'd want to bother with any other algorithm since brute force is really fast: it's almost linear time in the number of [411] pages; it tries at most 8 days. If you drop the the squaring it's perhaps more interesting, as it will try up to 46 days and there are no solutions, but sill finishes in under a second or so. Inverting the [sum of digits function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigitSum.html) is rather hard and its inverse is multi-valued... so I don't see why one should bother for this particular problem.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff Yes, inverting the function is hard in general, but by working modulo 9, one can get enough constraints that the problem is entirely solvable by hand.  I was actually expecting that a hand solution would be tedious with a lot of branching, but it turned out to be quite managable (and all the work is written up in my solution).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whatever you do, some case analysis is going to be required, as a function that is explicitly dependent on the digits of a number is not usually mathematically nice to work with.  However, since our function involves the sum of the digits, a quantity that only depends on our number modulo 9, we can at least save a little work.

Let $s(n)$ be the sum of the digits in the natural number $n$.  If $f(n)$ is the function that tells us what page we end on a day of reading if we start on page $n$, we can write $f(n)=n+s(n)^2.$  If we write $g^{(k)}$ for the $k$-fold composition of $g$ with itself (i.e., $g\circ g \circ g \circ \cdots \circ g$, with $k$ $g$'s), then we are trying to solve $f^{(5)}(n)=411.$

Since $s(n) \equiv n \pmod 9$, we have $f(n)\equiv n^2+n \pmod 9$.  (Note, there are not nice formulas for $s(n)$ modulo most numbers, 9 is special).  Using this, we can compute what composing $f$ multiple times does, at least mod 9.  Under $f$, we have the following chains:

$$\{1,4,7\}\mapsto 2 \mapsto 6\mapsto 6\mapsto \cdots, \qquad 8\mapsto 0 \mapsto 0 \mapsto \cdots, \qquad 5\mapsto 3 \mapsto 3 \mapsto \cdots$$

For example, if on the first day we started with a page congruent to 5 mod 9, every day afterwards we would be on a page congruent to 3 mod 9.

Since $411\equiv 6 \pmod 9$, we know we are in the case of the first cycle: we must start on a page congruent to either 1, 2, 4, 6, or 7 mod 9, and from the third day onward, we will start on a page congruent to 6 mod 9.

Using this, we will try to work backwards.  If $f^{(5)}(n)=f(f^{(4)}(n))=411$, what possible values can we have for $f^{(4)}(n)$.  We know it is a three digit number (whose first digit is at most 4) congruent to $6$ mod 9.  The sum of the digits must therefore be either $6$ or $15$ (as $9+9+4<24$), and therefore, if $f(y)=411$ with $y\equiv 6 \pmod 9$, either $y+6^2=411$ or $y+15^2=411$.  However, in the first case, $y=375$, but the sum of the digits in $375$ is not $6$, and therefore we have $y=411-15^2=186$.  We check, of course, that the sum of the digits in $186$ is indeed equal to $15$.  Now, we've reduced the problem to solving $f^{(4)}(n)=186$.

Again, as before, we have that $f^{(3)}(n)\equiv 6 \pmod 9$, and therefore has a digit sum of either 6 or 15, making it either $186-6^2=150$ or $186-15^2$, which is negative.  Therefore, $f^{(3)}(n)=150$.

We also know that $f^{(2)}(n)\equiv 6 \pmod 9$, and for the same reasoning as before, we conclude that $f^{(2)}(n)=150-6^2=114$.

Unfortunately, things get more complicated here, as $f(n)$ could be congruent to either $2$ or $6$ mod $9$.  Since 114<11^2, we know the digit sum of $f(n)$ is at most 10, and hence is either 2 (in which case $f(n)=114-2^2=110$, which does have a digit sum of $2$), or 6 (in which case $f(n)=114-6^2=78$, which does not have a digit sum of $6$ and can be ruled out).  Therefore, $f(n)=110$.

Now, things get even messier.  We have that $n$ is congruent to either $1, 4,$ or $7$, modulo 9, and we have to check each case individually to see what happens.  Again, the digit sum of $n$ is less than 11, which means $s(n)\in \{1, 4, 7, 10\}$, and so  $n=110-s(n)^2$ is one of $109, 94, 61,$ or $10$, whose corresponding digit sums are 10, 13, 7, and 1 respectively.  Of these, we only have one matchup: $n=61.$

Comment: How do you know "We know it is a *three digit number* (whose first digit is at most 4) congruent to 6 mod 9" at the first step [186]? The larges value for the dssq (as I called this function) is 441 (=21*21) for this interval [1:410]... so it could well be the case that its argument is just a single digit number at this step... at least without more reasoning.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff Apologies, I had meant "at most three digit number." Alternatively, I was allowing any of the three digits to be zero.  However, I am reluctant to edit, as clarifying will make the sentence a bit awkward.  My main concern was that we could easily bound the digit sum.

Comment: There were a couple of errors in your answer, but I've edited them and now it's perfect.

Answer (score 3):

### I found it, it's $61$.

First day 61.
Next day(2): $61+7^2=110$
Next day(3): $110+2^2=114$
Next day(4): $114+6^2=150$
Next day(5): $150+6^2=186$
Next day(6): $186+15^2=411$

---

### Here's some data

P.S. I used the code to even print latex!

### The number of pages read on first day that end up to 411 pages, not necessarily in 6 days:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{pages read $\\$on first day}&\text{days required to$\\$ read exactly 411 pages}\\\hline
13&5\\
16&4\\
29&4\\
\huge \color{red}{61}&\huge \color{red}{6}\\
65&3\\
110&5\\
114&4\\
150&3\\
186&2\\
190&3\\
241&3\\
290&2\\
\end{array}$$

---

### Code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class ADG {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    for (int firstpage = 1; firstpage <= 411; firstpage++) {
      int sum = firstpage;
      int day = 1;
      do {
        sum += squareofroot(sum);
        day++;
        if (sum == 411) {
          System.out.println(firstpage + "&" + day + "\\\\");
          break;
        }
      } while (sum <= 411);
    }
  }
  public static int squareofroot(int pnum) {
    int root = 0;
    int j = 0;
    do {
      root += pnum % 10;
      pnum = pnum / 10;
      j = j + 1;
    } while (pnum != 0);
    return (root * root);
  }

}
```

Comment: I guess the OP was less than impressed for this being brute force, but I've upvoted you for saving me some time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you'd solve it with somewhat less brute force... in `R`. I haven't bothered to write a full program, but the snippets are more insightful of how Leibnitz would have done it on paper. First you need to table the whole sum of digit squares function up to 410 (well, I've done it to 411). So first do define

```
digitsum <- function(x) sum(floor(x / 10^(0:(nchar(x) - 1))) %% 10)
```

thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/18675519/3588161. Then:

```
ds <- sapply(1:411, digitsum)
dssq <- ds * ds
dayX <- 1:411 + dssq
```

`dayX` is your lookup table for solving the equation $y=x+\mathrm{dssq}(x)$ where $x$ is the unknown. First solve for the last day:

```
which(dayX==411)
[1] 186 290
```

So there are two candidates; note from ADG's answer that one of these [186] is correct, the other is not. Welcome to multi-valued inverses. Now if we choose 290 it turns you'll have to do some backtracking.

```
which(dayX==290)
[1] 190 241

which(dayX==241)
integer(0)
```

So 290, 241 can't be a solution. What about 290, 190?

```
which(dayX==190)
integer(0)
```

Can't be either. So try 186...

```
which(dayX==186)
[1]  65 150
```

Note (from ADG's answer) that 186, 150 will lead to a solution. Etc.

---

EDIT: Aaron's idea of mod 9 checks (which I didn't I didn't see before posting my solution) gives a good criterion for quickly cutting some branches. For example, $290 \mod 9 = 2$ so 290 cannot lead to a solution of length more than 2 (days), given Aaron's chains.

Not that you actually need it much (if you tabled the whole function)... most of the time there's only one case to try from this point, except for 150 having both 29 and 114 as inverses; 29 mod 2 is again 2 so you could prune it that way (since you still need 3 more days). Here's the whole shebang:

```
which(dayX==150)
[1]  29 114
which(dayX==29)
[1] 13
which(dayX==13)
integer(0)
which(dayX==114)
[1] 110
which(dayX==110)
[1] 61
which(dayX==61)
integer(0)
```

For curiosity's sake here's chains of the same length (6) that you can find in that tabled function (up to 411) via transitive closure (repeated composition).

```
dayX[dayX[dayX[dayX[dayX]]]]

  [1] 303 339 183 321 471 564  NA 396 414 312 348 327 447  NA 573  NA
 [17] 405  NA  NA 357 471  NA  NA 582  NA 414  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 363
 [33]  NA 501  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 507  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 [49]  NA  NA  NA 402  NA  NA  NA  NA 507  NA  NA  NA 411  NA 711  NA
 [65]  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 720  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 711
 [81] 486  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 [97]  NA  NA  NA 402 438 417  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 447  NA  NA
[113]  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
[129]  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
[145]  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 501  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
[161]  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

The rest of the rows are just "NA" because I don't have the function tabled that far. This repeated composition is basically brute force however (but for all end values, not just 411). There are even longer chains though (length 7) for end values below 411, but there are none for length 8 (days):

```
 dayX[dayX[dayX[dayX[dayX[dayX]]]]]
  [1] 339 564 327 357  NA  NA  NA 720  NA 348 573 471  NA  NA  NA  NA
 [17] 486  NA  NA 582  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 507
 [33]  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 [49]  NA  NA  NA 438  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 447  NA  NA  NA
 [65]  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 [81]  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 [97]  NA  NA  NA 438  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
[113]  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA


 dayX[dayX[dayX[dayX[dayX[dayX[dayX]]]]]]
  [1] 564  NA 471 582  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 573  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```